# Add a class to HTML document in AngularJS app, after loading json?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, angularjs

I want to add some `css-classes` into my html document. When I use my app without `json`(simple `$scope.resumes = [{..some data..}]`) it works nice, but when I include json file it works bad(i see necessary data, but without css-classes)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ResumeListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.title="resume";
    $http.get(window.location+'/js/resumes.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.resumes= data;
    });
  });

$(document).on("ready", function() {
    $(".box:even").addClass("hvr-bubble-right").addClass("margin_right_5").addClass("box-float-right");
    $(".box:odd").addClass("hvr-bubble-left").addClass("margin_left_5").addClass("box-float-left");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
            <div class="expa col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"  ng-repeat="resume in resumes">
                <div class="box" >
                    <h3 class="h3-style">{{resume.name}}</h3>
                    <div class="description_company_name"><span>{{resume.company}}</span><span><i
                            class="fa fa-circle"></i></span><span>{{resume.year}}</span></div>
                    <div class="hidden-xs">
                       {{resume.description}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You should try to add the classes using angular, that way you can modify variables in the scope, also classnames. Using jQuery and Angular like this could give you weird results I guess

Comment: Take jQuery.js out of your page while learning angular. Only put it in when you find a real need for it

Answer (score 6):

Use `ng-class-even` and `ng-class-odd` like this:

```
<div class="box" ng-class-odd="'hvr-bubble-left margin_left_5 box-float-left'" ng-class-even="'hvr-bubble-right margin_right_5 box-float-right'">
   <h3 class="h3-style">{{resume.name}}</h3>
   <div class="description_company_name"><span>{{resume.company}}</span><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span><span>{{resume.year}}</span></div>
    <div class="hidden-xs">{{resume.description}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaximDreddoff You arw welcome. Make sure to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the append class on document ready, it might be too early.

Insert these two:

```
$(".box:even").addClass("hvr-bubble-right").addClass("margin_right_5").addClass("box-float-right");
$(".box:odd").addClass("hvr-bubble-left").addClass("margin_left_5").addClass("box-float-left");
```

In here

```
$http.get(window.location+'/js/resumes.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.resumes= data;
});
```

When the document is ready does not mean that the JSON post is also ready :)